# throw ArgumentError("nullColumnHack required when inserting no data");Exception in Flutter

Tags: flutter, sqflite

I am working on SqFlite programme but it shows ArgumentError Exception.
My code is not working it showing I can not insert data into database.
Please some one help me with this.SQFlite Operation like CRUD is not performing.

Exception like ArgumentError Exception like occurring some default dart file with Exception Showing.
Exception  throw ArgumentError("nullColumnHack required when inserting no data");

```
import 'dart:async';
import 'dart:io';
import 'package:sqflite/sqflite.dart';
import 'package:path_provider/path_provider.dart';
import 'package:sqlite_app/models/note.dart';


class DatabaseHelper {
  static DatabaseHelper _databaseHelper;
  static Database _database;
  String noteTable = 'note_table';
  String colId = 'id';
  String colTitle = 'title';
  String colDescription = 'description';
  String colPriority = 'priority';
  String colDate = 'date';


  DatabaseHelper._createInstance();

  factory DatabaseHelper(){
    if (_databaseHelper == null) {
      _databaseHelper = DatabaseHelper._createInstance();
    }

    return _databaseHelper;
  }


  Future<Database> get databse async {
    if (_database == null) {
      _database = await initalizeDatabase();
    }
    return _database;
  }

  Future<Database> initalizeDatabase() async {
    Directory directory = await getApplicationDocumentsDirectory();
    String path = directory.path + 'note.db';
    var noteDatabase = await openDatabase(
        path, version: 1, onCreate: _createDb);
    return noteDatabase;
  }

  void _createDb(Database db, int newVersion) async {
    await db.execute(
        'CREATE TABLE $noteTable ($colId INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,$colTitle TEXT,'
            '$colDescription TEXT,$colPriority INTEGER,$colDate TEXT)');
  }


  Future<List<Map<String, dynamic>>> getNoteMapList() async {
    Database db = await this.databse;
    //var result=await db.rawQuery('SELECT * FROM $noteTable order by $colPriority ASC');
    var result = await db.query(noteTable, orderBy: '$colPriority ASC');
    return result;
  }


  Future<int> insertNote(Note note) async {
    Database db = await this.databse;
    var result = await db.insert(noteTable, note.toMap());
    return result;
  }


  Future<int> updateNote(Note note) async {
    var db = await this.databse;
    var result = await db.update(
        noteTable, note.toMap(), where: '$colId=?', whereArgs: [note.id]);
    return result;
  }

  Future<int> deleteNote(int id) async {
    var db = await this.databse;
    int result = await db.rawDelete('DELETE FROM $noteTable WHERE $colId=$id');
    return result;
  }


  Future<int> getCount() async {
    Database db = await this.databse;
    List<Map<String, dynamic>> x = await db.rawQuery(
        "SELECT COUNT (*) from $noteTable");
    int result = Sqflite.firstIntValue(x);
    return result;
  }


  Future<List<Note>> getNoteList() async {
    var noteMapList = await getNoteMapList();
    int count = noteMapList.length;
    List<Note> noteList = List<Note>();
    for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
      noteList.add(Note.fromMapObject(noteMapList[i]));
    }
    return noteList;
  }
}
```

Comment: Can you put the full exception please

Comment: throw ArgumentError("nullColumnHack required when inserting no data");

Answer (score 1):

Just pass one more argument in db.insert(i.e. nullColumnHack) with value equal to the Auto Incrementing ID Integer...it will work...Do this for all other operations...

```
      Future<int> insertNote(Note note) async {
      Database db = await this.databse;
      var result = await db.insert(noteTable, note.toMap(),nullColumnHack: colId);
      return result;
      }
```